# Hypotenuse known , the ratio width : height known, How to find width and height value?

Tags: ratio, rectangles

Premises:

The nature of the problem is with respect to TV dimension.
I came across this when i was planing fo TV space required to mount onto my Wall.

Question:

How to find width and height of rectangle?

Known Value.

- the ratio of width to height is 16:9.
- the hypotenuse is 42 inch (106.68cm)

Comment: Look up the [Pythagorean Theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to solve it formally: let $H$ be the hypotenuse, $h,w$ the height and width, $r$ the ratio $w/h$. Just apply Pythagoras' theorem:
$$H^2=h^2+w^2= (1+r^2)h^2,\enspace\text{so }\quad h=\frac H{\sqrt{1+r^2}},\quad w=\frac {Hr}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just trig functions

$$w = opposite$$
$$h = adjacent$$
$$r (ratio) = \frac{w}{h} $$
$$H = hypotenuse$$
$$\arctan(\frac{w}{h}) = A$$
$$\sin(A) = \frac{w}{H}$$
$$\cos(A) = \frac{h}{H}$$
$$h = \sin(\arctan(r)) * H$$
$$w = \cos(\arctan(r)) * H$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $w=16k$, $h=9k$ to get $42^2=w^2+h^2=16^2 k^2+9^2 k^2=(256+81)k^2=337 k^2$. Then $k=\frac{42}{\sqrt{337}}$ and therefore $w=\frac{42}{\sqrt{337}}16$ and $h=\frac{42}{\sqrt{337}}9$.
         Note that $\frac{42}{\sqrt{337}}\approx 2.28$.